# Wallet connection issue in android Tronlink pro App

Tags: tron, tronweb

My Dapp is running peacefully on chrom using **tronlink** extension and in ios **Trust wallet** app
But this is not working with **Tronlink pro**,**Tron pocket**, **Trust wallet** in android

Is there any additional thing that i have to do to run my Dapp on these platform?

I am using https://github.com/fbsobreira/tf-example for connection.

Some of the android phone users are able to make connection by clearing cache again and again in **Tronlink pro** App

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Am having JS application. I tried to connect wallet using tronweb(window.tronWeb). For me not working in android and ios. But working perfectly in TronLink Chrome extension.